# Naming collection of variables at once in SAS

Tags: arrays, loops, variables, sas

I am trying to create 46 variables, indexed from 0-45 dependent on 3 other variables, each of which is indexed from 0-45. It seems as though the array approach would be the most straightforward but I can't get it to work. So i have variables a_0,...,a_45,b_0,...,b_45,c_0,...,c_45 and i want to create d_i=a_i+b_i+c_i but I'm having some difficulty. 
Attempt:

```
data test;
    set test;
    array d [0:45]; 
    array a [0:45] a_0-a_45;
    array b [0:45] b_0-b_45;
    array c [0:45] c_0-c_45;

    do i=0 to 45;
        d[i]=a[i]+b[i]+c[i];
    end;
run;
```

1) I can't seem to get the index from 0.

2) Whenever I run checks, the variables never add up in the intended way.

Comment: This also seems like a good reason to transpose your data to a long format instead of wide, if that's an option at all, you should consider it.

Answer (score 0):

try changing array d defintion.

```
    array d [0:45];
```

to

```
 array d [0:45] d0-d45;
```

In case of array d [0:45] it creates d1 to d46 whereas in case of array d [0:45] d_0-d_45  you explicitly index from 0 to 45.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't tell SAS what variable names to use for the array it will just create names using the array name and adding a numeric suffix.  So when you wrote

```
array d [0:45];
```

You told it to create 46 variables named `d1` to `d46`.

You could tell it what names to use.

```
array d [0:45] d_0 - d_45 ;
```

Also in the code you posted it doesn't really matter whether your index variable's value matches the numeric suffix on the variable names.  So why not make it much simpler.

```
array a a_0-a_45;
array b b_0-b_45;
array c c_0-c_45;
array d d_0-d_45; 
do i=1 to dim(a);
  d(i)=a(i)+b(i)+c(i);
end;
```

You could also just number your variables starting with 1 instead of Zero and save a lot of headache.